# why I get error when I try to print [string * Intger] in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**I am beginner in ruby language so, I tried to print this line**

```
   a = 2  
   z = "A"
   print a * z
```

then I get this Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
    19: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `load'
    18: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.3.7/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from (irb):24:in `<main>'
(irb):24:in `*': String can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
```

But when I tried to using this code it's work in the right way and I didn't receive any error

```
puts z * 2

or 

puts "A" * 2 

or 
 
z*a     
HERE I DON'T USE PRINT, PUTS, P
```

**so why I got the error in the beginning example and what is the Mechanism of Action of two code**

Comment: Look a little closer. The first time was ```integer*string```. The second 2 examples were ```string*integer```. Check out this thread for a more refined answer as to why those behave differently:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311429/multiplying-string-by-integer-vs-integer-by-string-in-ruby/39311454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the variable names to represent their types and simplify the explanation.

```rb
string = 'A' # from z = 'A'
integer = 2  # from a = 2
```

Next, let's identify what does the `*` operator ([method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm)) does:

```rb
# string * integer -> new_string
# returns a new `String` containing `integer` copies of the receiver.

puts string * integer  # repeat A twice
# "AA"
```

In the above, a string responds to `*` and accepts an integer argument.
The other examples perform a multiplication:

```rb
# integer * integer -> numeric_result
# performs multiplication

puts integer * 2  # multiply 2 by 2
# 4
```

> so why I got the error in the beginning example

Because string's `*` operator/method *requires an integer argument*.

> HERE I DON'T USE PRINT, PUTS, P

`print`, `puts` and `p` simply *output* the result of the operation or a statement, they just behave differently. You can still see the result without using them (in IRB or Rails console)

```rb
'A' * 2
# => 'AA'

2 * 2
# => 4
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer: the order matters.

`a * z` is basically equivalent to `a.send(:*, z)` meaning you call a `*` method on `a` and pass `z` as its argument,

and

`z * a` is `z.send(:*, a)` meaning calling `*` method on `z` object, and passing `a` as an argument.

So... if you check the docs:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-2A
string's `*` method expects int as it's argument, and

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-2A
int's `*` expects a numeric (int or float) to be passed as an argument.

Or, to put it differently, * (and +,- etc.) are not operators in Ruby (like they are operators in C or other langs) but are just what is called a syntactic sugar to make your life easier, but are in fact methods on the objects.